# Views exposed taxonomy filter - show only terms within results

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a block display with an exposed 'term' filter using [BEF](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) links filter.
I have the need to reduce the terms to display only the ones that show within the blocks results.

For example I have 'term1', 'term2', 'term3' - then if within the results there is only 'term1', 'term2' - I need to remove 'term3' from the list of filter links.

I realize that the filter is built before display so I am having difficulty grasping how the filter can be modified depending on what is in the display.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [views_hacks](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks). Specifically refer to [Views Selective Exposed Filters (views_filters_selective)](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_filters_selective)

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in the option, as well. Just getting to that issue on a new project.  Hard to believe that it is a built-in feature at filter level. But, would be a good feature request for the BEF module -- perhaps you could add it to issue queue.

Comment: @ Greta - did you manage to achieve this? I still have not worked it out.